# Print balance in CSV using Ledger cli

Tags: software

Ledger (http://ledger-cli.org/) allows to output reverse sorted balance of your Income accounts using the following command:

```
ledger -f money.txt bal Income --sort "-abs(total)"
```

so the output looks like follows:

```
  $-7,715.00  Income
  $-6,789.10    Payroll
    $-567.89    Insurance
    $-234.56    Gift Card
    $-200.56      Store 1  
     $-34.00      Store 2
    $-123.45    Coupons
```

Is there a way to output the same information in CSV format, but keeping the indentation of the categories as follows (header values are not important)?

```
    "Amount","Level 1","Level 2,"Level 3"
    $-7,715.00,Income,,
    ,$-6,789.10,Payroll,
    ,$-567.89,Insurance,
    ,$-234.56,Gift Card,
    ,,$-200.56,Store 1
    ,,$-34.00,Store 2
    ,$-123.45,Coupons,
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about coding.

Answer (score 2):

The Ledger documentation says that it has [a csv command](http://ledger-cli.org/3.0/doc/ledger3.html#The-csv-command) built in, so you could try that.

Alternatively it would be quite easy to post-process the type of output you have provided to the format you want. Tools such as `sed` or `awk` would do this for you.

Comment: Unfortunately csv command is a bit limited for this kind of operation. Yes sed/awk can certainly achieve that, I was hoping to get it working by the means of ledger itself, since running it in Windows environment.

Comment: Heading rapidly off topic, but you can get Unix utilities for Windows (without having to install Cygwin etc.) - I use them a lot. Search for UnixUtils or GnuWin32.

Comment: I end up doing it manually through excel, which is ugly. Will look into UnixUtils - good idea!